# Encountered unsupported property ComparisonOperator

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

Cloudformation stack throws Error **"Encountered unsupported property Comparison Operator"** , while creating an AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm using cloudformation.

As per AWS documentation **ComparisionOperator** value **GreaterThanOrEqualtoThreshold** is valid. 
I use AWSTemplateFormatVersion as **2010-09-09**

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
"CPUHighAlarm":{
            "Type":"AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties":{
                "AlarmDescription":"High CPU utilization",
                "MetricName":"CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace":"AWS/EC2",
                "AlarmActions":[{"Ref":"asgScaleOut"}],
                "ComparisionOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualtoThreshold",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "1",
                "Threshold": "70",
                "Period":"180",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Dimensions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "asg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo. Should be [`ComparisonOperator`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-comparisonoperator) instead of `ComparisionOperator`.

The [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) can help you catch these quicker and the [Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) can help prevent typos with autocompletion:

`E3002: Invalid Property Resources/CPUHighAlarm/Properties/ComparisionOperator`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's case sensitive. Try `GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...But No luck, I've tried with GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold as well